# how to install ScientificPython for Anaconda

Tags: python, pip, anaconda

I want to use ScientificPython in Anaconda. And I find a package in pip: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ScientificPython/2.6

Then I input the commond:
`pip install --allow-external ScientificPython==2.6`
but it give an error :
`You must give at least one requirement to install (see "pip help install")`

So, could you tell me how to install ScientificPython in Anaconda ? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

[`--allow-external` option](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/reference/pip_install.html#cmdoption--allow-external) take a value (package name):

```
pip install --allow-external ScientificPython ScientificPython==2.6
```

Comment: Thank you! I input this commond, but it said "Double requirement given: ScientificPython==2.6 (aready in ScientificPython, name='ScientificPython')". So, it doesn`t work...

Comment: @MichaelSheen, Did you speicfy as I show in the answer? `pip install --allow-external ScientificPython ScientificPython==2.6` It seems like you specified as follow: `pip install --allow-external ScientificPython==2.6 ScientificPython==2.6`